# jQuery is not defined, if defined, doesn't gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the width of an element after the page got loaded. For that I use this script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-6");

            for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i += 1){
                y[i].style.width = "100%";
            }
        });
</script>
```

But it isn't working. If I replace the `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` with a real function, lets say `changeWidth()` it is working..

Try it yourself [here](https://radlvoo.de/produkt/trek-super-commuter-8-2017-rh-groesse-55/). You can see, that this one will expand if you call `changeWidth()` in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUjvG.png)

Further, if I leave that out `type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'`, it says:

`jQuery is not defined`

What is the reason for this and how can I fix that?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-6");

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i += 1){
            y[i].style.width = "100%";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Nothing like that @Difster... :) I know you are too good....

Comment: Okay, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></s‌​cript>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var y = jQuery(".col-sm-6");
        y.each(function() {
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But then I get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):65
(index):78 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):78`

Comment: You need to include jquery before of this code.. like: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://radlvoo.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'></script>`